# C# WPF LiveChart Update data series in dynamicly created charts

Tags: c#, wpf, livecharts

Can anyone give advice on how to update all dynamicly created charts(10-12 charts) with dynamicly created series(3-5 series per chart) code below on how charts and series are created:
Page part where all charts and pages are assembled:

```
        public ChartPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        for(int i = 0; i < ChartConnector.FoundMainData; i++)
        {
            GroupedCharts SC = new GroupedCharts();
            foreach (string SGDO in ChartConnector.MainDataTable[i].SecondLevelData.Keys)
            {


                SingleChartObject SingleChart = new SingleChartObject ();

                for (int z = 0; z < ChartConnector.MainDataTable[i].SecondLevelData[SGDO].FoundThirdLevelData; z++)
                {
                    SingleChart.AddNewLineToChart(ChartConnector.MainDataTable[i].SecondLevelData[SGDO].ThirdLevelData[z].ThirdLevelDataName, Convert.ToDouble(ChartConnector.MainDataTable[i].SecondLevelData[SGDO].ThirdLevelData[z].ThirdLevelDataValue));
                }
                SC.AddChartToGroup(SingleChart);
            }
            ChartList.Children.Add(SC);
        }
    }
```

ChartList in ChartPage xaml

```
<StackPanel x:Name="ChartList"></StackPanel>
```

GroupedCharts are UserControl which stores charts from second level data
GroupedCharts AddChartToGroup function below:

```
public void AddChartToGroup(SensorChart ChartBlock)
    {
         ChartGroup.Children.Add(ChartBlock);
    }
```

Chartgroup in xaml code below:

```
<WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" x:Name="ChartGroup"></WrapPanel>
```

SingleChartObject also are Usercontrol which has LiveChart and add series in it, AddNewLineToChart function code below :

```
 public void AddNewLineToChart(string Name, double Value)
    {
        ChartValues<LiveCharts.Defaults.ObservableValue> observableValues = new ChartValues<LiveCharts.Defaults.ObservableValue>
        {
            new LiveCharts.Defaults.ObservableValue(Value)
        };
        LiveCharts.Wpf.LineSeries FreshLines = new LineSeries
        {
            Values = observableValues,
            Title = Name

        };
        ChartBlock.Series.Add(FreshLines);
    }
```

Chart it self in SingleChartObject

```
<lvc:CartesianChart x:Name="ChartBlock" Height="125" Width="300" Pan="None" >
            <lvc:CartesianChart.DataTooltip>
                <lvc:DefaultTooltip SelectionMode="SharedYInSeries" />
            </lvc:CartesianChart.DataTooltip>
        </lvc:CartesianChart>
```

Now main question how to update all charts at a same time, I have no idea on how to do such massive update. Thanks for help.

Comment: What If I store each chart instance index and then using index update values in each chart this is just theory?

Comment: Could this idea work, if yes how i do get each chart instance?

Answer (score 0):

You should use MVVM pattern in your application. Instead of using "ChartList" as StackPanel, better use an 'ItemsControl' and set its ItemTemplate with 'GroupedCharts'. Also create a view model for this 'GroupedChart' user control. Set the items source with collection of this view model. You have to do one level nesting to achieve what you want.
Once your view is controlled by view model, it will automatically update your view. But for that you have to properly implement MVVM pattern.